# How do I use a for loop with input and output streams?

Tags: java, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm practicing the file reader and writer methods in Java, I wrote this code and doesn't work as expected, advice please...

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileOutputStream obj = new FileOutputStream("D:\\testout.txt");
        String s = "Hello world";
        byte c[] = s.getBytes();
        obj.write(c);
        obj.close();
        System.out.println("thanks, file created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);;
    }

    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream("D:\\testout.txt");
    int i;
    /*while ((i = reader.read())!= -1) {
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
    reader.close(); */

    for(i = 0; i <= reader.read(); i++) {
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
    reader.close();
}
}
```

when using the "while" function it works, but when replacing it with "for" it shows symbols, what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: did you mean to say it does not work with `for`? The `while` and `for` loops you wrote are not equivalent.

Comment: the for-loop is primarily used for numbering: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) println("digit " + i);` . You do not read into i.  `for (; (i = reader.read()) >= 0; )` would be the correct loop, `while` being much nicer.

Comment: @Bentaye I mean, it works with "while" but doesn't work with "for", sorry I'm gonna correct that ...

Comment: @JoopEggen, interesting, thanks man for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [reader.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) it reads the next byte in the stream, Java doc says:

> **returns:** the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

so when you do `reader.read()`, it simply returns an `int`, which is the representation of the first byte of the stream. It can be anything, depending on the first byte of your stream. Let's say in your case it returns `8`

So when you do

```
 for(i = 0; i <= reader.read(); i++) {
     System.out.print((char)i);
 }
```

you are effectively doing

```
 for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
     System.out.print((char)i);
 }
```

And you are just printing the char values of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8.

You are not printing the bytes from the stream

The `while` loop on the other hand, does the right job, it keeps calling the read() method and reads every byte of the stream, until the method returns `-1` and that means that we reached the end of the file.